# How to move a rectangle around a canvas in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-canvas

I have a canvas with a rectangle that I would like to be able to move around. With a Composable, I know how to use the dragging modifier as described here: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/gestures#dragging

But my canvas rectangle has no modifier:

```
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
        drawRect(Color.Blue, topLeft = Offset(0f, 0f), size = Size(this.size.width, 55f))
```

So how can I drag it? Is there a way with Compose or is it better to just use the native way with a native canvas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

With `1.0.0-beta04` you can use the **`pointerInput`** modifier in the `Canvas` to control the dragging gesture through the [**`detectDragGestures`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/gestures/package-summary.html#detectdraggestures) function and save the `Offset` and apply it in the `topLeft` parameter in the `drawRect`.

```
var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                change.consumeAllChanges()
                offsetX += dragAmount.x
                offsetY += dragAmount.y
            }
        }
    ){
    val canvasQuadrantSize = size / 2F
    drawRect(
        topLeft = Offset(offsetX,offsetY),
        color = Color.Green,
        size = canvasQuadrantSize
    )
}
```

[image]